# How to create custom reward for a review in Magento Sweettooth

Tags: php, magento

I just began working on a Magento web store and we would like to add a feature to the [Sweettooth rewards plugin](https://www.sweettoothrewards.com/).

We would like to reward a customer 2 points for a review on any product, but limit this to 10 reviews per month. I contacted Sweettooth support, and thay said they don't have a feature like this implemented yet, and that I would have to create it myself.

As I am fairly new to Magento and Sweettooth, I really don't have an idea of where to begin. Has anyone created a custom thing like this before? And how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Building this while respecting the coding standards and structure would imply creating a new module, adding an observer to catch the review create/save events, writing your own logic for what conditions should be met, checking those conditions and lastly using the public Sweettooth methods to add the reward points.

Comment: All of the above means 2 things: 1) your problem is too vast / unclear to approach directly; 2) you need to break your problem down into multiple stages of work, see what to begin with, start working on what you can do and come back and when you find a sub-task you don't know how to do come back here and ask a clearer more concise question about that particular sub-task.

Comment: Also [Alan Storm's Blog](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento) is a very good resource to learn Magento basics including how to build your first module.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I kinda thought it would be a big project. I'll just start digging around in the code to understand how it all works.

Comment: Another generic advice (this time not related to your question): if you find solutions on the internet telling you to "change this file at line #NNN" in the core of Magento or in another module (like Sweettooth)  it's pretty much telling you to break the common good practices which are there for a couple of reasons (such as upgradeability and maintainability). For store owners who just want to fix their own site and don't care about upgrading or future maintenance (even though they should) it may be OK (it's not really but at least it's their business decision), but for developers it's not.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to directly edit the Sweettooth files because we are going to have to update it eventually. Thanks again for the advice. Looks like I've got a bit of work to do!

Comment: Sweet Tooth actually already has the functionality to reward for reviewing a product... what it's missing, is the ability to *limit* how many times the customer can be rewarded for that.  It should be much simpler to just stop the reward from going through under your conditions, rather than re-implementing Sweet Tooth's existing review features just for this change.  I will post an answer shortly.